# How do i display the outcome of my for loop with if statement in an html tag like a paragraph

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, innerhtml, getelementbyid

So the first for loop is what i had for a default console.log and the second on is the one i tried to do it with, but no good outcome sadly.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) console.log("FB");
    else if (i % 3 == 0) console.log("F");
    else if (i % 5 == 0) console.log("B");
    else console.log(i);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML = "FB";
    else if (i % 3 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML = "F";
    else if (i % 5 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML = "B";
    else document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-light">Opdracht 2</h2>
    <p class="text-light" id="fizzbuzz"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? If you are waiting for "100" to appear in your paragraph, that won't ever happen, because your code is always going to `else if (i % 5 == 0)` in last loop, because 100 % 5, is 0.

Comment: If I understand, you should append to your #fizzbuzz element instead of replacing it eg  document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML += "FB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [@36ve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2974567/36ve) mentioned in his comment on your question, and based on additional informations you gave I guess you should change your code from assigment to string concatenation.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML += "FB ";
    else if (i % 3 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML += "F ";
    else if (i % 5 == 0) document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML += "B ";
    else document.getElementById("fizzbuzz").innerHTML += `${i} `;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-light">Opdracht 2</h2>
    <p class="text-light" id="fizzbuzz"></p>
</div>
```